# Class Skill and Skill Focus as requirement for feat

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, feat-qualifications

The answer is probably, "no you have burn another feat for this," but I wanted to ask the community anyway.

I am looking at taking the [Eldritch Heritage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/eldritch-heritage) feat with my Dhampir Oracle and one of the requirements is:

> Skill Focus with the class skill of bloodline selected for this feat

I already have the skill as a class skill and have ranks in it so does that count or do I have to take the [Skill Focus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/skill-focus---final) feat first?

I assume if it were Class Skill or Skill Focus then the text would say so, but I just want to make sure I am not missing something that would allow me to skip taking an extra feat to get this one.

Comment: The "class skill" bit means the skill is the relevant Class Skill for the Bloodline you select, not that you have it as a Class Skill. The only requirement is the Skill Focus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not missing anything.
**If the text says the feat is a prerequisite, it is.**
The only case where I could see a way to avoid that would be any other feat that "counts as Skill Focus for satisfying the prerequisites of other feats/PrCs/other" (D&D 3.5 had a couple of similar ones,  e.g. Desert Wind Dodge substituting Dodge)

Comment: 3.5’s Aereni Focus is an example of a feat explicitly qualifying as Skill Focus, for what it’s worth.

Comment: Thanks.
I am creating a new character starting at lvl 10 and had two feat slots left to pick. I guess I just filled them both up.

Comment: @James: you might want to wait 2-3 days before accepting an answer. People might stop answering if they see there's already one accepted answer (they shouldn't, anyway) and theirs might be better than mine.

Comment: Okay. I'll remember that for the future.